# How to execute shell scripts?

Tags: bash, github-actions

```
├── .github
│   └── workflows
│       ├── cd.yml
│       └── ci.yml
├── scripts
│   ├── createDevEBAppVersion.sh
│   └── createProdEBAppVersion.sh
├── src
```

Github Actions throws the following error:

> /home/runner/work/_temp/9c99fa0d-20da-49ed-a0af-322f274c13ac.sh: line 1: [refs/heads/develop: No such file or directory
>
> /home/runner/work/_temp/9c99fa0d-20da-49ed-a0af-322f274c13ac.sh: line 5: [[refs/heads/develop: No such file or directory

```yml
name: CD

env:
  PACKAGE_NAME          : "app_${GITHUB_SHA::8}.zip"
  ARTIFACT_ROOT         : "${GITHUB_REF#refs/*/}"
  APPLICATION_NAME      : "example-app-name"
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     : ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY }}
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY : ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_KEY }}
  AWS_REGION            : ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
  AWS_BUCKET            : ${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME }}

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
    paths-ignore:
      - '**.json'
      - '**.md'
  release:
    tags:
      - 'v*'

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Create ZIP package artifact
      run: git archive --format=zip HEAD -o ${{ env.PACKAGE_NAME }}

    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}

    - name: Copy package artifact to S3 bucket
      run: |
        aws s3 cp ${{ env.PACKAGE_NAME }} s3://${{ env.AWS_BUCKET }}/${{ env.APPLICATION_NAME }}/
        echo "✔ Artifact uploaded successfully to s3://${{ env.AWS_BUCKET }}/${{ env.APPLICATION_NAME }}/${{ env.PACKAGE_NAME }}"

    - name: Create new ElasticBeanstalk Application Version
      working-directory: scripts
      run : |
        if ["${{ github.ref }}" == "refs/heads/develop"]; then
          chmod +x ./createDevEBAppVersion.sh
          ./createDevEBAppVersion.sh
        fi
        if [["${{ github.ref }}" == *"refs/tags/v"*]]; then
          chmod +x ./createProdEBAppVersion.sh
          ./createProdEBAppVersion.sh
        fi

    ...
```

I've tried without having `working-directory`, but it didn't work.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version \
--application-name ${{ env.APPLICATION_NAME }} \
--source-bundle S3Bucket="${{ env.AWS_BUCKET }}",S3Key="${{ env.APPLICATION_NAME }}/${{ env.PACKAGE_NAME }}" \
--version-label "${{ env.PACKAGE_NAME }}" \
--description "Application version created from https://github.com/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/actions/runs/$GITHUB_RUN_ID"
echo "✔ Deployment triggered successfully."
```

It seems like CI had problems finding a file. How can I execute `createDevEBAppVersion.sh`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your error message is:

```
/home/runner/work/_temp/9c99fa0d-20da-49ed-a0af-322f274c13ac.sh: line 1: [refs/heads/develop: No such file or directory
```

It's trying to execute `[refs/heads/develop` and failing.  The root cause is that you're missing a space between the bracket and the test.  You want:

```
if [ "${{ github.ref }}" == "refs/heads/develop" ]; then
```

(And the same on line 5.)

That's because `if` in bourne shells actually *runs a command* that it evaluates.  Although it looks like it's evaluating an expression, it's actually passing an expression to a command called `[`.

```
% ls -Flas /bin/\[
 8 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  22704 May  4  2019 /bin/[*
```

This is often a symlink (or hardlink) to `/bin/test`, and in some shells, like bash and zsh, `[` will actually be a shell built-in:

```
% which '['
[: shell built-in command
```

But it still behaves like a command, and syntactically, it needs the space.  Because:

```
if [ true ]; then ...
```

Runs the `[` command (or shell-builtin) to evaluate the `/bin/true` command.  And

```
if [true ]; then ...
```

Tries to run the nonexistent `[true` command.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had no idea the space between the bracket was required.

Comment: Do I still need to define `working-directory: scripts`?

Comment: Yes, if you refer to them as `./createProdEBAppVersion.sh`.  You could also run `scripts/createProdEBAppVersion.sh` and omit the `working-directory`